# Setting GCP environment variable in Spring boot with vs code

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to set up GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS but keep getting this error

> java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credential

I have defined in my application properties:

```
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=PROJECT_ID
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=lasspath:/src/main/resources/key.json
```

Added the dependency in the pom file:

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
     <artifactId>google-cloud-dialogflow</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Tried to do it from the terminal(windows) as well no luck:

```
> set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\user\Desktop\****\******\src\main\resources\key.json"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by running in the terminal:

```
$env:GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\Users\user\Desktop\*****\****\src\main\resources\*****.json"
```

In addition to setting the relevant role in IAM section of GCP since I've encountered a  PERMISSION_DENIED Error after

Answer (score 1):

If you have Google Cloud SDK installed you can run this command in the console to set up application default credentials:

> gcloud auth application-default login

Please, see more details in the documentation:
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default